# AvalonDock MVVM Anchorable Location

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I have an AvalonDock (version 3.5) in my MVVM WPF application. The binding is as follows:

```
    <xcad:DockingManager Name="_dockingManager" Grid.Row="1" 
DataContext="{Binding DockingManagerViewModel}"
                     DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                     AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}" >
```

So when I add a new Anchorable to the corresponding "Anchorables" collection in my view model the corresponding view shows up. Nevertheless the views always show up docked on the right side of my application. How can I control that the view is docked on the left side of my application via the view model?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can control this in you viewmodel.

There 2 ways for controlling this.

1. You can restore the layout from a previously saved (default) layout whenever the
    application is started for te first time or
2. You can setup the XAML to use an initial layout as you wish (prefered solution)

For the second option:
You can use the XAML binding in the [DockingManager](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/wiki/DockingManager#Side-Panel-Properties) class to implement your requirement:

See [TestApp](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/wiki/TestApp) sample for full implementation of the below snippet (just change LeftSide to BottomSide to see the effect):

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager Grid.Row="1">
...
    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="AutoHide1 Content" ContentId="AutoHide1Content" IconSource="/AvalonDock.TestApp;component/Images/address-book--pencil.png" >
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TestTimer, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='AutoHide Attached to Timer ->\{0\}'}"/>
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="AutoHide2 Content" ContentId="AutoHide2Content">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBox/>
                        <TextBox/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
</avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property (call it `InitialPosition`, or something like that) to your Anchorable view model, and implement a `ILayoutUpdateStrategy` to position the anchorable on the left, right or bottom side.

Add something like this to your XAML:

```
<xcad:DockingManager …>
   …
   <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
        <local:LayoutUpdate />
   </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>

</xcad:DockingManager>
```

and your `LayoutUpdate` class:

```
class LayoutUpdate: ILayoutUpdateStrategy
{
    static Dictionary<PaneLocation, string> _paneNames = new Dictionary<PaneLocation, string>
    {
        { PaneLocation.Left, "LeftPane" },
        { PaneLocation.Right, "RightPane" },
        { PaneLocation.Bottom, "BottomPane" },
    };

    public bool BeforeInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableToShow, ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
    {
        if (anchorableToShow.Content is IAnchorable anch)
        {
            var initLocation = anch.InitialLocation;
            string paneName = _paneNames[initLocation];
            var anchPane = layout.Descendents()
                           .OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>()
                           .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == paneName);

            if (anchPane == null)
            {
                 anchPane = CreateAnchorablePane(layout, Orientation.Horizontal, initLocation);
            }
            anchPane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static LayoutAnchorablePane CreateAnchorablePane(LayoutRoot layout, Orientation orientation,
                PaneLocation initLocation)
    {
        var parent = layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutPanel>().First(d => d.Orientation == orientation);
        string paneName = _paneNames[initLocation];
        var toolsPane = new LayoutAnchorablePane { Name = paneName };
        if (initLocation == PaneLocation.Left)
            parent.InsertChildAt(0, toolsPane);
        else
            parent.Children.Add(toolsPane);
        return toolsPane;
    }

    public void AfterInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorable)
    {
        // here set the initial dimensions (DockWidth or DockHeight, depending on location) of your anchorable
    }
```

This code is extracted and changed a bit from the working application, with different types and names. It should probably work, but there might be a typo or other error somewhere.